# Dask - large merge and map_partitions/apply - hangs on last couple tasks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

This code starts with a table with about 19K records and does a join that results in about 600 million rows.

Everything runs really fast, but processing hangs seemingly indefinitely on the last couple tasks.

Running on a two machine cluster, each machine with 32GB of ram and 8 cores.

It seems Dask should be able to handle this. Can't understand why its hanging. Tried smaller and greater numbers of npartitions on the .merge, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

See example code and screen shot below.

```
from textdistance import levenshtein
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

if __name__ == '__main__':

    client= Client('local_ip:8786')

    names = []
    for i in range(18994):
        names.append('Doe, John')
    names.append('Arnold Boden')
    names.append('Arneld Buden')
    names.append('John Fish')
    names.append('Jawn Fish')
    names.append('Michael Burger')
    names.append('Bichael Murger')
    ids = []
    for i in range(19000):
        ids.append(i)
    x = pd.DataFrame({'Full Name': names, 'Person Number':ids})
    my_df = dd.from_pandas(x, npartitions=8)

    my_df['dummy'] = 1
    my_df = my_df[['dummy', 'Full Name']]

    my_join = my_df.merge(my_df, how='inner', on='dummy', npartitions=200)

    def is_lev_match(row):

        name_1 = row['Full Name_x']
        name_2 = row['Full Name_y']

        if (levenshtein.distance(name_1, name_2) <= 2) and (name_1 != name_2):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    my_join['c_is_lev_match'] = my_join.map_partitions(
        lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: is_lev_match(row), axis=1)
    )

    lev_matches = my_join[my_join['c_is_lev_match'] == True]

    lev_matches.to_csv(r'\\machine_running_code\e\temp_x\lev_temp-*.csv',
                       header_first_partition_only=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Ba. This example code just failed with memory error. Any idea how to optimize this? numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.69 GiB for an array with shape (361000000,) and data type int64

Comment: Looks like you're doing record linkage... maybe you have seen this, but in case not: https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/